# Привет, выдает ошибку после команды строчки "Break"

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Начал писать типа "СВОЮ ИГРУ" на Python, пишу, пишу. А в циклах я не разбираюсь. Можете помочь?

````
name = "Яша"
surname = "Лава"
age = 15
livein = "Москва"
school = "Школа №2127"
work = "Монитрощик цен в Магазинах"
balance = 500
sleep = 10
Brain = 0

while True:
print("Привет, я", name, surname)
print("Мне ", age)
print("Я живу в ", livein)
print("Я учусь в ",school)
print("Я работаю на ", work)
print("Сейчас у меня на карте:", balance)  
print("Есть команды: Стоп, Работать, Учиться, Спать")
answer = str(input());
if answer == 'Стоп':
    break
if answer == 'Работать':
    print("Вы начали работать. Прошло 2 часа 30 минут. \nИтоги: Получено 500$ на Карту. Сейчас у вас:", balance + 500)
if answer == 'Спать':
    print("Сейчас вы получили. Вы получили +2 очка сна. Сейчас у вас:", sleep + 2)
if answer == 'Учиться':
    print('Вы пошли в Школу. Прошло 5 часов, вы получили +15 ума. Сейчас у вас', Brain + 15)
else:
    print("Ты забыл? Команды: Стоп, Работать, Учиться, Спать.")```
````

Comment: Кажется, вы забыли написать вопрос

Comment: Ошибку показывает в **break**

Comment: Чего только за пять минут не напишешь

Answer (score 2):

Забыл табуляции поставить, в твоем коде так называемая ошибка `"This code is unreachable"`, вложенность после `While` обязательна. Преобразование к типу `str` в `input` не обязательна, потому что `input` по умолчанию все данные в строку преобразует. Точка с запятой там же не нужна. Названия переменных рекомендуется писать в `"snake_case"`, например, `live_in` и `brain` в твоем случае. Так читаемость кода увеличивается. Лучше использовать один тип кавычек в коде, либо только двойные, либо только одинарные. Ну и хорошей практикой будет использование F-строк, они позволяют вставлять переменные напрямую в строку без проебразования типа данных.

```
name = "Яша"
surname = "Лава"
age = 15
live_in = "Москва"
school = "Школа №2127"
work = "Монитрощик цен в Магазинах"
balance = 500
sleep = 10
brain = 0

while True:
    print(f"Привет, я {name} {surname}")
    print(f"Мне {age}")
    print(f"Я живу в {live_in}")
    print(f"Я учусь в {school}")
    print(f"Я работаю на {work}")
    print(f"Сейчас у меня на карте: {balance}")
    print("Есть команды: Стоп, Работать, Учиться, Спать")
    answer = input()
    if answer == "Стоп":
        break
    if answer == "Работать":
        print("Вы начали работать. Прошло 2 часа 30 минут. \n"
              f"Итоги: Получено 500$ на Карту. Сейчас у вас: {balance + 500}")
    if answer == "Спать":
        print(f"Сейчас вы получили. Вы получили +2 очка сна. Сейчас у вас: {sleep + 2}")
    if answer == "Учиться":
        print(f"Вы пошли в Школу. Прошло 5 часов, вы получили +15 ума. Сейчас у вас {brain + 15}")
    else:
        print("Ты забыл? Команды: Стоп, Работать, Учиться, Спать.")
```

Comment: Полагаю, если он не знает о табуляции в пайтоне, твои слова с его точки зрения будут выглядеть примерно так: 请问，厕所在哪里